# Fastest way to quote one side of an SQL comparison

Tags: c#, string, oracle

I am generating SQL code for different types of databases. To do that dynamically, certain parameters of the SQL script are stored in variables.

One such stored parameter is the comparison expression for certain queries.
Lets say I have a Dogs table with a Name, DateOfBirth and Gender columns, then I have comparison expressions in a variable such as:

```
string myExpression = "Gender=1";
string myExpression2 = "Gender=1 AND Name='Bucky'";
```

I would build the following SQL string then:

```
string mySqlString = "SELECT * FROM "dbo"."Dogs" WHERE " + myExpression;
```

The problem is, that for Oracle syntax, I have to quote the column names (as seen at dbo.Dogs above). So I need to create a string from the stored expression which looks like:

```
string quotedExpression = "\"Gender\"=1";
```

Is there a fast way, to do this? I was thinking of splitting the string at the comparison symbol, but then I would cut the symbol itself, and it wouldn't work on complex conditions either. I could iterate through the whole string, but that would include lot of conditions to check (the comparison symbol can be more than one character (<>) or a keyword (ANY,ALL,etc.)), and I rather avoid lots of loops.

Comment: I would go with EF and LINQ and let it do the dirty work for me.

Comment: This is not necessarily the case: you may not need to quote every column names. Have you tried without quotes?

Comment: Yes, sadly it throws ORA-00904 error, "Invalid identifier GENDER".

Answer (score 1):

IMO the problem here is the attempt to use `myExpression` / `myExpression2` as naked SQL strings. In addition to being a massive SQL-injection hole, it causes problems like you're seeing now. When I need to do this, I treat the filter expression as a DSL, which I then parse into an AST (using something like a modified shunting yard algorithm - although there are other ways to do it). So I end up with

```
AND
   =
      Gender
      1
   =
      Name
      'Bucky'
```

Now I can walk that tree (visitor pattern), looking at each. `1` looks like an integer (`int.TryParse` etc), so we can add a parameter with that value. `'Bucky'` looks like a string literal (via the quotes), so we can add a string-based parameter with the value `Bucky` (no quotes in the actual value). The other two are non-quoted strings, so they are column names. We check them against our model (white-list), and apply any necessary SQL syntax such as escaping - and perhaps aliasing (it might be `Name` in the DSL, but `XX_Name2_ChangeMe` in the database). If the column *isn't* found in the model: reject it. If you can't understand an expression completely: reject it.

Yes, this is more complex, but it will keep you safe and sane.

There may be libraries that can already do the expression parsing (to AST) for you.